# Trucks are parked in storage when driver goes on vacation. Modify table designs to accommodate this: Mark X on Code that needs to be removed

Tags: mysql

Trucks are parked in storage when driver goes on vacation. Modify table designs to accommodate this

```
CREATE TABLE Truck (
TruckID Primary Key,
Type VARCHAR(30),
DriverID INT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Driver (
DriverID INT NOT NULL,
Somefield VARCHAR(32),
TruckID INT NOT NULL);
```

Mark X on Code that needs to be removed
My assumption would be to remove DriverID since the driver is no longer on site then we can just track the trucks or delete the Driver code completely? Not sure if that would be accurate and would love some guidance. The above is all that was presented in the question.

Comment: seems like we would just want to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on the `driverid` column in `Truck`. To have a `Truck` not be assigned to a `Driver`, we can set the `driverid` column to NULL. We can make the same change to `truckid` column on the `Driver` table (set `truckid` to NULL if there is no truck assigned to the driver. Also, the `truckid` column in `Truck` needs a datatype. If we want to keep a history, we need more than one-to-one relationship, ...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you!